# 'node \r node no such file or directory' while running ionic platform add ios

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic project. Everything was fine until I have not updated ionic and cordova for mac machine **Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2**. After updating this components I could not run **ionic build ios** and it was  giving  error so I tried to remove platform and add it again but it given following error and now I am unable to proceed

> env: node\r: No such file or directory Error: Hook failed with error
>   code 127: /hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js

How can I get over this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I come to a solution on following link
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-hook-failed-with-error-code-127/12236

> Issue
>
> This is due to to OSX ^M line endings that were committed to my
>   project in this file. For some reason they seem to pop up in this file
>   only, although I have seen some SO posts where people are having the
>   problem on other node scripts.

check if the file has ^M line endings

**`cat -v FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR`**

fix the file

**`tr -d '\r' < FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR > FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR.fix`**

check if problem fixed in resulting file from above

**`cat -v FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR.fix`**

overwrite original file with fixed file

**`mv FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR.fix  FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR`**

Not only **`after_platform_class.js`** file but error in other files like
`install_plugin.js, register_plugin.js, deregister_plugin.js` can also be resolved with this solution